# ArcMap attribute joins generating incorrect values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins

**Background:**

At 10.8.1, ArcMap attribute joins run without complaint, yet generate incorrect results.

As shown in the screenshot below, the tables **component** (parent) and **chorizon** (child) are joined 1:1, each via the field *cokey*.

Both are file geodatabase attribute tables, stored in the same FGDB.

I have conducted the join using two different techniques:

1. From the attribute table window dropdown > Joins and Relates > Join... (both with the Keep all Records and Keep only Matching Records options, always using the Validate Join button)
2. Using the Add Join tool (with Keep All Target Features unchecked)

**Problem:**

When reviewing the output, I notice that some of the child table values are incorrect following the join.  For example, the screenshot shows two selected rows where the joined *sandtotal_r* values are different than the source table (6.8 vs. 63.7 and 13.5 vs. 29.5).  In fact, 6.8 and 13.5 do not exist anywhere in the source attribute table!

The incorrect values always appear, regardless of the join method used.

When I conduct the join using QGIS 3.18.2, the output is correct.  Thus it appears that the problem is with ArcMap, not the data.

Any thoughts?

@FelixIP suggested I try the Join Field tool, which worked correctly.  However, the original problem still exists.  I suspect a bug.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Join field? It will update first table with fields of your choice from second

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `cokey` values in the `chorizon` table are unique?  Sort the table by `cokey` (double click on that column header), and scroll down to that value(s) again to confirm.

Comment: That's my first thought (@SonofaBeach) the values are not unique. Another way to see if they are not unique is to run the summary statistics table, count on `ObjectID` and case is `cokey`. Advantage of this is that you can sort by count and find all the duplicates.

Comment: Which soil survey is this, so I can try to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I queried one of my friends at the National Soil Survey Center. Here is their response:

> There isn’t a bug.
>
> The problem is that SSURGO is a relational database and you can’t use
> simple joins in ArcGIS on any of the tables with the exception of
> ‘muaggat’ and ‘mapunit’. All of the other tables are one-to-many. This
> issue is discussed in both the gSSURGO and SSURGO documentation.
>
> They can also see the relationships by clicking on a soil polygon with
> the Identify tool. The Identify window will allow the user to drill
> down through the mapunit->component->chorizon->.. tables and see the
> related records that way. The only way to generate a soil map for a
> horizon-level soil property is to run some sort of summarization
> process. The ArcToolbox on the following gSSURGO website should allow
> them to do that using the ‘Create Soil Map’ tool.
>
> https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/soils/survey/geo/?cid=nrcs142p2_053628